# If $P = (A,B)$ is a point chosen randomly and uniformly in a disc of radius $R$, are $A$ and $B$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

My intuition is that the answer is yes, but I have no way how to justify this.

Moreover, how do we go about computing $P(\text{max}(A,B) = R/2)$ ?

Comment: They are not independent. If A is very close to R, then B needs to be small (just one example).

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we may take the center of the disk to be the origin. Consider $P(A>\frac {3R}4, B>\frac {3R}4)$. This is $0$ because $(3R/4)^{2}+(3R/4)^{2}>R$. But independence would give $P(A>\frac {3R}4, B>\frac {3R}4)=P(A>\frac {3R}4)P( B>\frac {3R}4)$. This is a contradiction because $P(A>\frac {3R}4)>0$ and $P(B>\frac {3R}4)>0$. [I will let you supply a proof of this fact]. Hence, $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

$A$ and $B$ have continuous distributions. [In fact, you can explicitly compute their pdf's]. $\max (A,B)=\frac  R 2$ implies $A=\frac  R 2$ or $B=\frac  R 2$ and these happen with probability $0$. Hence, $P(\max (A,B)=\frac  R 2)=0$.